# Hive2 & JDBC - Required field 'serverProtocolVersion' is unset

Tags: java, hadoop, jdbc, hive

I am trying to connect to hive using 
Driver org.apache.hive.jdbc.HiveDriver

```
 private static String driverName = "org.apache.hive.jdbc.HiveDriver";


  public void (String query)throws SQLException {
    try {
      Class.forName(driverName);
    } catch (ClassNotFoundException e) {
      // TODO Auto-generated catch block
      e.printStackTrace();
      System.exit(1);
    }
    Connection con = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:hive2://localhost:10000/default", "", "");
    Statement stmt = con.createStatement();
    String tableName = "testHiveTable";
    stmt.executeQuery("drop table " + tableName);
    ResultSet res = stmt.executeQuery("create table " + tableName + " as "+query);
```

Getting the following error

```
java.sql.SQLException: Could not establish connection to jdbc:hive2://localhost:10000/default: Required field 'serverProtocolVersion' is unset! Struct:TOpenSessionResp(status:TStatus(statusCode:SUCCESS_STATUS), serverProtocolVersion:null, sessionHandle:TSessionHandle(sessionId:THandleIdentifier(guid:4A D8 C1 6F 82 54 49 05 80 77 24 7D A2 3A 1D 9A, secret:21 9B BF EA 37 B6 49 60 BE 5F D2 13 98 E3 17 0B)), configuration:{})
```

Comment: which JDBC are you using ?

Comment: Have a look on it : http://hortonworks.com/community/forums/topic/connection-refused-to-hiveserver2-via-jdbc/

Comment: Checked it is not having solution+

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had the same issue. Setting username in method [getConnection](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/sql/DriverManager.html#getConnection-java.lang.String-java.lang.String-java.lang.String-) fixed my problem. Please see [HiveServer2 documentation](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/Hive/HiveServer2+Clients#HiveServer2Clients-UsingJDBC) for more details.