# ERROR jdbc.HiveConnection: Error opening session Hive

Tags: java, hadoop, jdbc, hive

i try to run JBDC code for Hive2 get error. i have hive 1.2.0 version hadoop 1.2.1 version.
but in command line hive and beeline works fine without any problem.but with jdbc getting error.

```
import java.sql.SQLException;
import java.sql.Connection;
import java.sql.ResultSet;
import java.sql.Statement;
import java.sql.DriverManager;

public class HiveJdbcClient {
  private static String driverName = "org.apache.hive.jdbc.HiveDriver";

  /**
   * @param args
   * @throws SQLException
   */
  public static void main(String[] args) throws SQLException {
//BasicConfigurator.configure();

  try {
      Class.forName(driverName);
    } catch (ClassNotFoundException e) {
      // TODO Auto-generated catch block
      e.printStackTrace();
    }
    //replace "hive" here with the name of the user the queries should run as
    Connection con = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:hive2://localhost:10000/default","", "");
    Statement stmt = con.createStatement();
    String tableName = "cdr";
   stmt.execute("drop table if exists " + tableName);
// show tables
    String sql = "show tables '" + tableName + "'";
    System.out.println("Running: " + sql);
    ResultSet res = stmt.executeQuery(sql);
    if (res.next()) {
      System.out.println(res.getString(1));
    }

  }
}
```

**i Get this Error While Run Code.**

```
15/06/19 12:08:53 INFO jdbc.HiveConnection: Will try to open client transport with JDBC Uri: jdbc:hive2://localhost:10000/default
15/06/19 12:08:53 ERROR jdbc.HiveConnection: Error opening session
org.apache.thrift.TApplicationException: Required field 'client_protocol' is unset! Struct:TOpenSessionReq(client_protocol:null, configuration:{use:database=default})
        at org.apache.thrift.TApplicationException.read(TApplicationException.java:111)
        at org.apache.thrift.TServiceClient.receiveBase(TServiceClient.java:71)
        at org.apache.hive.service.cli.thrift.TCLIService$Client.recv_OpenSession(TCLIService.java:156)
        at org.apache.hive.service.cli.thrift.TCLIService$Client.OpenSession(TCLIService.java:143)
        at org.apache.hive.jdbc.HiveConnection.openSession(HiveConnection.java:578)
        at org.apache.hive.jdbc.HiveConnection.<init>(HiveConnection.java:192)
        at org.apache.hive.jdbc.HiveDriver.connect(HiveDriver.java:105)
        at java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(DriverManager.java:571)
        at java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(DriverManager.java:215)
        at HiveJdbcClient.main(HiveJdbcClient.java:24)
Exception in thread "main" java.sql.SQLException: Could not establish connection to jdbc:hive2://localhost:10000/default: Required field 'client_protocol' is unset! Struct:TOpenSessionReq(client_protocol:null, configuration:{use:database=default})
        at org.apache.hive.jdbc.HiveConnection.openSession(HiveConnection.java:589)
        at org.apache.hive.jdbc.HiveConnection.<init>(HiveConnection.java:192)
        at org.apache.hive.jdbc.HiveDriver.connect(HiveDriver.java:105)
        at java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(DriverManager.java:571)
        at java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(DriverManager.java:215)
        at HiveJdbcClient.main(HiveJdbcClient.java:24)
Caused by: org.apache.thrift.TApplicationException: Required field 'client_protocol' is unset! Struct:TOpenSessionReq(client_protocol:null, configuration:{use:database=default})
```

Any Solution ?

Answer (score 21, accepted):

> org.apache.thrift.TApplicationException: **Required field
>   'client_protocol' is unset!**
>   Struct:TOpenSessionReq(client_protocol:null,
>   configuration:{use:database=default})
>           at org.apache.thrift.TApplicationException.read(TApplicationException.java:111)

This error mostly occurs if you have **version mismatch** between your hive and hive-jdbc. Please check if both the versions match.

Please refer [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24694415/required-field-client-protocol-is-unset) for more information.

Answer (score 3):

This happens when a new version of JDBC driver is used against older version of HiveServer2.
Use a jdbc driver that is same version as server (preferred), or an version that is older than the server.

The issue is tracked in https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/HIVE-6050

Answer (score 0):

"client_protocol" field is available in hive 1.1 version.
You need to add hive-service-1.1.0.jar in classpath.

I hope your problem would get solved.