# hive-warehouse-connector_2.11 + Required field 'client_protocol' is unset

Tags: hive, cloudera, spark2

I am using a hadoop cluster with cloudera-6.3.2 distribution.
I have a requirement to read hive ACID table from spark (Java client). So native spark does not read hive acid table. Hence planning to use Hive WareHouse Connector. But getting below exceptions.Even could not read non acid table also. Any Thoughts?

```
20/03/27 21:26:46 INFO HiveWarehouseSessionImpl: Created a new HWC session: 9f46ffe3-c863-4fbf-82ef-9f730f0c0cfc
    20/03/27 21:26:47 INFO LlapBaseInputFormat: Handle ID 6439738b-a20a-46cc-9ee3-63214b573660: query=select * from test
    20/03/27 21:26:47 ERROR HiveConnection: Error opening session
    org.apache.thrift.TApplicationException: Required field 'client_protocol' is unset! Struct:TOpenSessionReq(client_protocol:null, configuration:{set:hiveconf:hive.server2.thrift.resultset.default.fetch.size=1000, use:database=default/})
        at org.apache.thrift.TApplicationException.read(TApplicationException.java:111)
        at org.apache.thrift.TServiceClient.receiveBase(TServiceClient.java:79)
```

Java Code

```
HiveWarehouseSession hive = HiveWarehouseSession.session(spark).build();
 hive.executeQuery("select * from test").show();
```

Here is my pom.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>fw_analytics</groupId>
    <artifactId>com.analytics</artifactId>
    <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <configuration>
                    <source>8</source>
                    <target>8</target>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
    <packaging>jar</packaging>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.spark</groupId>
            <artifactId>spark-core_2.11</artifactId>
            <version>2.4.0-cdh6.3.2</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.spark</groupId>
            <artifactId>spark-hive_2.11</artifactId>
            <version>2.4.0-cdh6.3.2</version>
        </dependency>


        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.hortonworks.hive</groupId>
            <artifactId>hive-warehouse-connector_2.11</artifactId>
            <version>1.0.0.7.0.3.0-79</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <repositories>
        <repository>
            <releases>
                <enabled>true</enabled>
            </releases>
            <snapshots>
                <enabled>true</enabled>
            </snapshots>
            <id>hortonworks.extrepo</id>
            <name>Hortonworks HDP</name>
            <url>http://repo.hortonworks.com/content/repositories/releases</url>
        </repository>
        <repository>
            <releases>
                <enabled>true</enabled>
            </releases>
            <snapshots>
                <enabled>true</enabled>
            </snapshots>
            <id>Cloudera.extrepo</id>
            <name>Cloudera HDP</name>
            <url>https://repository.cloudera.com/artifactory/cloudera-repos/</url>
        </repository>
        <repository>
            <releases>
                <enabled>true</enabled>
            </releases>
            <snapshots>
                <enabled>true</enabled>
            </snapshots>
            <id>hortonworks.other</id>
            <name>Hortonworks Other Dependencies</name>
            <url>http://repo.hortonworks.com/content/groups/public</url>
        </repository>
    </repositories>

</project>
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24694415/required-field-client-protocol-is-unset

Comment: Thanks fo the reply. I tried the above link before posting this question.. That did not work for me.. that is why I have posted pom.xml also to let you all know the versions that I am using.