# java.sql.SQLException: Could not open client transport with JDBC Uri

Tags: spring-boot, jdbc, hive

I am trying to connect to Hive, although login is successful I am getting the following error:

```
java.sql.SQLException: Could not open client transport with JDBC Uri: jdbc:hive2://server.domain.com:10000/default;principal=hive/server@CORPDEV.DOMAIN.COM;auth-kerberos?hive.mapred.mode=nonstrict: Could not establish connection to jdbc:hive2://server.domain.com:10000/default;principal=hive/server@CORPDEV.DOMAIN.COM;auth-kerberos?hive.mapred.mode=nonstrict: Required field 'client_protocol' is unset! Struct:TOpenSessionReq(client_protocol:null, configuration:{set:hiveconf:hive.mapred.mode=nonstrict, set:hiveconf:hive.server2.thrift.resultset.default.fetch.size=1000, use:database=default})
at org.apache.hive.jdbc.HiveConnection.<init>(HiveConnection.java:224)
at org.apache.hive.jdbc.HiveDriver.connect(HiveDriver.java:107)
at java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(DriverManager.java:664)
at java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(DriverManager.java:208)
at com.hive.util.JdbcClient.getConnection(JdbcClient.java:29)
at com.hive.util.JdbcClient.getResultSet(JdbcClient.java:151)
at com.hive.dbwrapper.HiveWrapper.getResultset(HiveWrapper.java:195)
at com.hive.Application.main(Application.java:24)

Caused by: java.sql.SQLException: Could not establish connection to jdbc:hive2://server.domain.com:10000/default;principal=hive/server@CORPDEV.DOMAIN.COM;auth-kerberos?hive.mapred.mode=nonstrict: Required field 'client_protocol' is unset! Struct:TOpenSessionReq(client_protocol:null, configuration:{set:hiveconf:hive.mapred.mode=nonstrict, set:hiveconf:hive.server2.thrift.resultset.default.fetch.size=1000, use:database=default})
at org.apache.hive.jdbc.HiveConnection.openSession(HiveConnection.java:699)
at org.apache.hive.jdbc.HiveConnection.<init>(HiveConnection.java:200)
... 7 more

Caused by: org.apache.thrift.TApplicationException: Required field 'client_protocol' is unset! Struct:TOpenSessionReq(client_protocol:null, configuration:{set:hiveconf:hive.mapred.mode=nonstrict, set:hiveconf:hive.server2.thrift.resultset.default.fetch.size=1000, use:database=default})
at org.apache.thrift.TApplicationException.read(TApplicationException.java:111)
at org.apache.thrift.TServiceClient.receiveBase(TServiceClient.java:79)
at org.apache.hive.service.rpc.thrift.TCLIService$Client.recv_OpenSession(TCLIService.java:168)
at org.apache.hive.service.rpc.thrift.TCLIService$Client.OpenSession(TCLIService.java:155)
at org.apache.hive.jdbc.HiveConnection.openSession(HiveConnection.java:680)
... 8 more

Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException
at com.hive.Application.main(Application.java:25)

2020-12-03 15:18:33.860 ERROR 14297 --- [           main] org.apache.hive.jdbc.HiveConnection      : Error opening session

org.apache.thrift.TApplicationException: Required field 'client_protocol' is unset! Struct:TOpenSessionReq(client_protocol:null, configuration:{set:hiveconf:hive.mapred.mode=nonstrict, set:hiveconf:hive.server2.thrift.resultset.default.fetch.size=1000, use:database=default})
at org.apache.thrift.TApplicationException.read(TApplicationException.java:111) ~[libthrift-0.9.3.jar:0.9.3]
at org.apache.thrift.TServiceClient.receiveBase(TServiceClient.java:79) ~[libthrift-0.9.3.jar:0.9.3]
at org.apache.hive.service.rpc.thrift.TCLIService$Client.recv_OpenSession(TCLIService.java:168) ~[hive-service-rpc-2.3.0.jar:2.3.0]
at org.apache.hive.service.rpc.thrift.TCLIService$Client.OpenSession(TCLIService.java:155) ~[hive-service-rpc-2.3.0.jar:2.3.0]
at org.apache.hive.jdbc.HiveConnection.openSession(HiveConnection.java:680) [hive-jdbc-2.3.0.jar:2.3.0]
at org.apache.hive.jdbc.HiveConnection.<init>(HiveConnection.java:200) [hive-jdbc-2.3.0.jar:2.3.0]
at org.apache.hive.jdbc.HiveDriver.connect(HiveDriver.java:107) [hive-jdbc-2.3.0.jar:2.3.0]
at java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(DriverManager.java:664) [na:1.8.0_161]
at java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(DriverManager.java:208) [na:1.8.0_161]
at com.hive.util.JdbcClient.getConnection(JdbcClient.java:29) [classes/:na]
at com.hive.util.JdbcClient.getResultSet(JdbcClient.java:151) [classes/:na]
at com.hive.dbwrapper.HiveWrapper.getResultset(HiveWrapper.java:195) [classes/:na]
at com.hive.Application.main(Application.java:24) [classes/:na]`
```

Following is the code snippet

```
 public class HiveWrapper

 public ResultSet getResultset(String query) {
    try {
        preConfig();
        this.client = new JdbcClient();

        if (this.extraJarPath != null && !this.extraJarPath.equals("")) {
            this.client.executeQuery(HIVEDRIVER, this.ctnString, prop, "ADD JAR " + this.extraJarPath);
        }
        return this.client.getResultSet(HIVEDRIVER, this.ctnString, prop, query);
    } catch (SQLException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return null;
}

private void preConfig() {
    if (this.ctnString == null || this.ctnString.equals("")) {
        generateConnectionString();
    }
    try {
        System.setProperty("javax.security.auth.useSubjectCredsOnly", "false");
        System.setProperty("java.security.krb5.conf", "hive/krb5.conf");

        Configuration conf = new Configuration();
        conf.addResource(new Path("hive/hive-site.xml"));
        conf.addResource(new Path("hive/core-site.xml"));
        conf.addResource(new Path("hive/hdfs-site.xml"));
        conf.set("hadoop.security.authentication", "kerberos");
        conf.set("hadoop.security.auth_to_local", this.securityAuth);
        UserGroupInformation.setConfiguration(conf);
        if (this.user != null && this.keytabPath != null) {
            UserGroupInformation.loginUserFromKeytab(this.user, this.keytabPath);
        }
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
}

public class JdbcClient {
public ResultSet getResultSet(String driverName, String connectionString, Properties prop,
                              String sql) throws SQLException {
    getConnection(driverName, connectionString, prop);
    if (this.con != null) {
        log.info("Connection created for " + connectionString);
        try {
            log.info("Running SQL: " + sql);
            stmt.setFetchSize(1000);
            resultSet = stmt.executeQuery(sql);
            return resultSet;
        } catch (SQLException e) {
            log.debug(e.getMessage());
            throw new SQLException(e.getMessage());
        }
    }
    return null;
}


private void getConnection(String driverName, String connectionString, Properties prop)
        throws SQLException {
    try {
        if (this.con == null) {
            Class.forName(driverName);
            this.con = DriverManager.getConnection(connectionString, prop);
            this.stmt = this.con.createStatement();
        }
    } catch (ClassNotFoundException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
}
```

The hive is running on a remote server. For hive I am adding the hive-site.xml, core-site.xml, hdfs-site.xml.
Can anyone please help me on this. I am new to hive. Not able to find the issue. May be I am missing something.

Comment: It says `Required field 'client_protocol' is unset!`

Comment: Related, possibly duplicate: [Required field 'client_protocol' is unset](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24694415/required-field-client-protocol-is-unset)